# Proving that a polynomial has no roots in a compact interval

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, roots

Suppose I have:

- a continuous function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with real coefficients, potentially of high degree, and
- an interval $[a,b] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

If $f$ has a root in $[a,b]$, proving this is pretty easy: either $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ have a different sign, in which case it follows from the intermediate value theorem that $f$ has a root in $[a,b]$, or else we can repeatedly bisect the interval until $f$ is a found to have a different sign at one of the points we're considering, at which point we have proven that $f$ has one or more roots in our original interval.

Suppose on the other hand the $f$ has no roots in $[a,b]$. Actually proving this seems, in general, to be a difficult task.

> **Question.** Supposing that $f$ is a polynomial function, and that this polynomial is explicitly known, but potentially of high degree (e.g. $\geq 6$), so that simply finding the turning points in exact form is out of the question. Are there any methods for proving that $f$ has no roots in $[a,b]$?

I was thinking that maybe we can use a numerical method to approximate the turning points to a desired level of precision and use this to show that the minimum value of $f$ is positive on $[a,b]$ is positive, or that it's maximum value on $[a,b]$ is negative.

Comment: How are the coefficients of the polynomial given? If the coefficients are rational numbers, there are classical methods for root isolation e.g., via [Sturm sequences or Uspesky's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm#Method_based_on_the_Budan–Fourier_theorem_or_Sturm_chains). If you are working over a larger field of coefficients, then you first have to solve the problem of effective computation in that field.

Comment: @RobArthan, right, good point. Let's just assume they're rational numbers, for the reason you give.

Comment: For a computer-assisted proof, you could use interval arithmetic with outward floating-point rounding (search for “validated numerics”).